# Maximum no. of laddoos of diameter $6$cm in a box of given dimension

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

> What is the maximum number of laddoos having diameter of $6\text{ cm}$ that can be packed in a box whose inner dimensions are $24\times 18\times 17\text{ cm$^3$}$.

I found that at the lower label maximum $12$  laddoos can be placed, and at the next upper label maximum $12$ laddos can be placed , and at the upper label maximum $6$ laddoos  can be placed. So total $12+12+6=30$ laddoos can be packed. But the given answer contradict my answer.

Please tell me where my fallacy ?

Comment: What if you tried the full 12 on the top and bottom layers, but the middle layers, place the balls in the same $yz$ plane, in the two troughs between the 3 balls in the 18cm direction.  Then you could get 4 rows of 2 balls in for a total of 12+8+12.  No sense to go full close-packing since it won't be enough to afford us a 4th layer.

Comment: Even better (and actually correct i think), place them in the three troughs between the 4 balls on the other plane.  Then you can get 3x3=9 in that middle row.

Comment: Actually I could not understand how in middle row there are $9$ balls ?

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Comment: Also, I learned what a laddoo was.

Comment: Laddoo.. an Indian delicacy, a sphere shaped sweet preparation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of us looking at one wall of the packing.  (Not the floor, but a side wall).  You can pack 4 along the bottom and top and put 3 in between them.  See (crude) attached image.  Then you can repeat this wall 3 times in the 18cm direction.

[image]

**ETA:** We know we can get away with this spacing vertically (the 17cm direction) because hexagonal circle packing gives is a layer height of appx $0.902414d$

Answer (score 0):

I found that at the lower label maximum 12 laddoos can be placed, and at the next upper label maximum 12 laddos can be placed , and at the upper label maximum 9 laddoos can be placed. So total 12+12+9=33 laddoos can be packed. which is the exect ans according to me

Comment: if this ans is wrog please give right ans